# como mudar o material de um objeto onclick

Tags: c#, unity3d

estou utilizando a unity3d, tenho um prefab de uma esfera e outro de um cubo, com um material simples e gostaria de saber como posso alterar o material desses objetos ao clicar em um botão na `UI`.

Answer (score 4):

Voce precisa referenciar o Componente Material Renderer deles no seu script... E assim que forem clicados, você troca esse material para outro do seu gosto.

No Prefab vc faz algo desse tipo:

```
public class Prefab : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Material MaterialAtual;
    public Material NovoMaterial; //Lembre-se de arrastá-lo no inspector

    void Start()
    {
        //Pegue o material dentro de prefab.
        MaterialAtual = this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material
    }

    void TrocarMaterial()
    {
        // Troque o material
        MaterialAtual = NovoMaterial;
    }
}
```

No Botão vc faz algo desse tipo:

```
public class Prefab : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Prefab cubo;  //vincule-os pelo inspector, arrastando o gameobject aqui
    public Prefab esfera;

    void Start(){
        this.onClick.AddListener(() => BotaoClicado();
    }

    void BotaoClicado()
    {
        cubo.TrocarMaterial();
        esfera.TrocarMaterial();
    }
}
```

Espero que isso ajude.

PS: Referencias - 
Eventos de Botões - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

Material Renderer - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-material.html

PS-2: Vc pode até mudar a cor do seu material sem ter que colocar outro, caso não se trate de uma textura complexa, ou algo do tipo.. Apenas acesse o valor color do material referenciado e troque-o, desse jeito: `MaterialAtual.color = cor-que-vc-quiser;`